# How many triple satisfy in inequality

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I found an Entrance Exam question like as:

How many triple like (A,B,C) from subsets of set {1,2,3,4} is true in following inequality :

$ A \cap B \subseteq C \subseteq A \cup B   $

any hint or idea?

Any nice solution?

Comment: 'triple from (A,B,C) from subsets'-??

Comment: dear @Alex, sorry edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the Venn diagram.  Each element of $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ is in exactly one of the following $6$ subsets of $X$:
$A\cap B$, $C\cap(A\setminus B)$, $C\cap(B\setminus A)$, $A\setminus C$, $B\setminus C$, $X\setminus (A\cup B)$.  The elements of $X$ can be assigned to these subsets independently, so there are $6^4=1296$ possibilities.